# YQL documentation for the google.news search and the "geo" key

Tags: geolocation, yql

Someone know some documentation of Yql Google News Search? I am trying understand the "geo" key values for the search.

This [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20google.news%20where%20q%20=%20%22new%20york%22) show a example for the search.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Cleber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details of the usage of the different keys on the YQL `google.news` table, see the source API's documentation.

In this case that can be found in the [Google News Search API - JSON Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/v1/jsondevguide.html), and the `geo` key is described as:

> This optional argument tells the News Search system to scope search results to a particular location. With this argument present, the query argument (`q`) becomes optional. You must supply either a city, state, province, country, or zip code as in `geo=Santa%20Barbara` or `geo=British%20Columbia` or `geo=Peru` or `geo=93108`.

It goes on to say:

> When using the `geo` property, please note the following:
>
> - Make sure the location you supply exists within the scope of your chosen news edition. For example, if you specify `geo=Quebec` for the Canadian edition of Google news, you probably won't get good results.
> - You can't combine `geo` with the `topic` property.
> - Some editions of News Search don't support the `geo` parameter. To test if `geo` works with a specific edition,
>
>   1. Go to that edition's landing page (for example, news.google.ca)
>   2. Click **Add a Section**.
>   3. In the **Add a Local Section** box on the right side of the page, enter a search query relevant to your desired location (for example, **Quebec**). You should now see a **Local Results** pane on the edition homepage.
>
> If the Local Results pane is populated with results, you can use the `geo` parameter for that region.